# Multi-level modeling - Dummy coded binary variable for the Time

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, multilevel-analysis

I am new to multi-level modeling.

I have a two level model.

- level_1 : times
- level_2 : times nested in days

Because I am interested in the effect of **different times intervals** within **each day**, I used dummy coded binary variables for time variable:

T1, T2, T3

I used lmer package in R :

```
lmer(my_dependent_variable ~ T1+T2+T3+
                 ...),
               data=dataset,
               REML = FALSE)
```

My questions are:

Q1- Do you think my notation is correct when I wanted to see the effect of different time intervals (T1, T2, T3) in each day? I tried those as my fixed components.

```
... my_dependent_variable ~ T1+T2+T3+ ...
```

Q2- If I remove random intercepts or random slopes on level two, the results will not change significantly. What does that mean? Is there any implication about it?